# SSIS Derived Column translated from SSMS query

Tags: ssis, derived-column

New to SSIS, been dealing with SSMS mostly. Anyone can help translating the below SSMS statement into SSIS Derived Column Transformation? Many thanks.

```
ReliabilityFactorInput  =  Case 
When (isnull(pn.LBOXMATL, 'OTHER') = 'OTHER' AND  (round(ISNull(edd.cal_year, eqd.YearManuf) + 1, -4)/10000<=2003) OR pn.LBOXMATL ='Cast Iron') AND (ceiling((pn.NOWAYS+1)/2)*2 >= 4) then '1.3'
When (isnull(pn.LBOXMATL, 'OTHER') = 'OTHER' AND  (round(ISNull(edd.cal_year, eqd.YearManuf) + 1, -4)/10000<=2003) OR pn.LBOXMATL = 'Cast Iron') AND  (ceiling((pn.NOWAYS+1)/2)*2 < 4) then '1.1'   
else '' 
End
```

Comment: I suggest you look here [link[ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487327/ssis-derived-column-if-then-else

Answer (score 0):

1.Name a variable with whatever name you want with int data type

2.Use execute sql task

3.copy  all the complete query into that task and specify the **result Set** to single row

4.Switch to Result Set page, choose the variable you create, and **set the result name** to 0

5.Now every time you run the package the variable will be assigned either 1.3 or 1.1

6. That variable could be used in **Derived Column** transformation in data flow now