# witing a case statement in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I'm setting up a package to import an excel spreadsheet into a SQL database. There is a column in the spreadsheet where I would like to pick out keywords and then put them in a new column.  In SQL it would be like a basic case statement

```sql
case when column_A like '%Norwich%' then 'Norwich'
    when column_A like '%Ipswich%' then 'Ipswich'
    when column_A like '%Cambridge%' then 'Cambridge'
    else 'NA'
end as NewColumn
```

I have tried the below but I'm guessing its not working properly because I have now wildcards

```
[Report Title] == "Norwich" ? "Norwich" : [Report Title] == "Ipswich" ? "Ipswich" : [Report Title] == "Cambridge" ? "Cambridge" : "NA"
```

*Example:*

```
Report Title                      NewColumn

Norwich is in Norfolk             Norwich
Cambridge is in Cambridgeshire    Cambridge
Suffolk is home to Ipswich        Ipswich
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Derived Column (if then...else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487327/ssis-derived-column-if-then-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `FINDSTRING()` function with nested conditional operators to achieve that:

```
FINDSTRING([Report Title],"Norwich",1) > 0 ? "Norwich" : (
FINDSTRING([Report Title],"Ipswich",1) > 0 ? "Ipswich" : (
FINDSTRING([Report Title],"Cambridge",1) > 0 ? "Cambridge" : "NA"))
```

**References**

- [Nested Conditional Operators in an SSIS Derived Column](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/6/8/nested-conditional-operators-in-an-ssis-derived-column.html)
- [FINDSTRING (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)